# Manually switch notificationListenerService on and off

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, android-service

How would you go about switching a notificationListenerService on and off manually using buttons?

At the moment the service starts the moment the app is allowed in Security->Notifications however I'm unsure how to prevent this and do it manually instead.

I realise there are functions such as startService() but am unsure how to implement this toward the service.

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of details missing. What are you talking of? Is it a programming problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int)) to enable or disable a service programmatically:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
ComponentName notificationListenerService = new ComponentName(this,
    YourNotificationListenerService.class);

// The new state of the service - either enabled or disabled
int newState = enableService
    ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
    : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLE;

packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
    notificationListenerService,
    newState,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```